# lxml.etree not found on macOS BigSur v11.5.1

Tags: python, lxml, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to use lxml.etree on Python 3.9.5 and I get the below error:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/4r/nslf5xyd54ldnyz40qhqh9z80000gn/T/ipykernel_5110/650422379.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lxml.etree as ET

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml.etree'
```

I use macOS BigSur v11.5.1.
I tried installing it with
`STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml` and even that didn't work.

I'm able to `import lxml` just fine though. Can someone please help me in getting this solved? Thanks!

Comment: What does `import lxml; print(lxml)` show?

Comment: @aaron: `import lxml

print(lxml)
<module 'lxml' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/__init__.py'>`

Comment: Well, that's not the Python 3.9.5 that you say you are using. Can you show your exact commands in the terminal involving `STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml` and your Python shell?

Comment: `~ % STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.8.0)` You're right, libraries are being installed in 3.10, but when I try to see the version of Python being used by Spyder, it shows this: `print (sys.version)
3.9.5 (default, May 25 2021, 07:41:55) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]`

Comment: @aaron - Looks like my Spyder was just using the default Python interpreter instead of Python 3.10. I changed the Python interpreter path and it's all working now. Thank you!